# Create an object based on other object

Tags: javascript

Say I have an object:

```
var obj1 = {var1: 123, var2: 456, var3: "fdsfdsfds"};
```

How can I create object 2 based on obj1 so that it has all the properties of obj1 and they all belong to other new key:

```
var obj2 = {parentKey: {var1: 123, var2: 456, var3: "fdsfdsfds"}};
```

The names of the keys -- var1, var2, var3 -- aren't known and they can be anything.

Answer (score 1):

In fact it is you is not using compiler like babel or other, it is necessary to use the following syntax:

```
var obj2 = {parentKey: Object.assign ({}, obj1)};
```

If you do not want your object to be immutable, you just have to do:

```
var obj2 = {parentKey: obj1};
```

Waiting for the standardization of ES2015, you must use a compiler to use this syntax:

```
const obj1 = {var1: 123, var2: 456, var3: "fdsfdsfds"};
const obj2 = {... obj1};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to *copy* the object, a simple way to do a simple-minded copy is the new `Object.assign` function (which can be shimmed for older environments);

```
var obj2 = {parentKey: Object.assign({}, obj1)};
```

If you don't mind using the **same** object (not a copy), you can just make it the value of the new object's `parentKey`:

```
var obj2 = {parentKey: obj1};
```